# How do I spread the $Shape of an object into an Exact object

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to spread an object definition provided by a third party library as optional properties on my exact object type.

Example:

```js
type Match = {
    params: { [key: string]: ?string, ... },
    isExact: boolean,
    path: string,
    url: string,
    ...
}

// Modified version of react-router-dom ContextRouter type for example purposes
type ContextRouter = {|
    history: string,
    location: string,
    match: Match,
|};

// Not working how I want it to
type Props = {|
    ...$Shape<ContextRouter>,
    match: { params: { [key: string]: ?string, ... } }
|};
```

The end goal is to allow these scenarios to work correctly:

```js
// I want this to be allowed (with history and location optional)
({
    match: {params: {id: '7'}}
}:Props);

// I want this to throw an error on the 'unknown' property
({
    match: {params: {id: '7'}},
    unknown: true
}:Props);
```

I want everything in `ContextRouter` to be optional. My example currently throws errors if any of the properties of `ContextRouter` are missing.

```js
22: ({     ^ Cannot cast object literal to `Props` because property `history` is missing in object literal [1] but exists in `Props` [2].
References:
22: ({     ^ [1]
24: }:Props);
      ^ [2]
```

I made a starting point here: [flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#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-wcnHonARAIIBISoG9ODw-quViDxDIocw4cjMbj9l9lerteobAcEB8iYJ5FTQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the [$Rest](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#resta-b-) utility type

From docs:

> `$Rest<{|n: number|}, {}>` will result in `{|n?: number|}` because an in-exact empty object may have an n property

Also, `$Shape` is [broken](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6906) with spreads.

Try [here](https://flow.org/try/#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-gB2f4yXwySj43SEz3Kt5qjXALUbTX5REmKAJfLNFKa6D-ByceicBEAggEhKgH04PABq5WYPEMhhzARqOx+P2P1Vmt16hsBwQHxJgnkNNAA)

Comment: It's a confusing way to do it, but it does work. Hopefully they fix $Shape which would make more sense while staring at code.